# Arrow to go to the main menu disappears

Tags: bug, ios-app

Arrow to go to the main menu disappears. This happens after visiting 10-20 questions. The app then restarts.

Phone data and Bug data is below:

- App Version: 1.6.6.2
- Device: IPhone XR (iPhone11,8)
- OS Version: Version 13.0 (Build 17A577)[image: Bug photo]

Comment: Can — and have way too often recently — reproduce. Also the app has started to hang a lot recently. Unfortunately, SE has explicitly said, a few years ago now, they are no longer actively maintaining the app, and don’t have any plans to. They want you to use the site in a mobile browser and take advantage of the the investment they made in responsive design.